# URL rewrite with two parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am stuck changing the htaccess file,

currently i am displaying pages like this after rewriting from htaccess:

```
www.domain.com/contact
```

which comes to be this url before rewriting from htaccess:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?show=contact
```

I am using this code to do the rewriting:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?show=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?show=$1 [L,QSA]
```

what i want to do now its set two parameters, eg:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?show=contact&id=3
```

which should display:

```
www.domain.com/contact
```

and inside that page i wanna be able to get ($_GET['id']) the id.

Please help me i am stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a separate rule to handle `/contact` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?show=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index\.php)?\?show=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?show=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?show=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, plus i have to be able to do this for multiple pages, not only contact. sorry

Comment: And do they all have `&id=3` in final URI?

Comment: the id changes as well

Comment: Wow! Hope you build some understanding for this. How will any rule magically know to add `&id=5` for /about-us` and `&id=3` to `/contact` for ex.?

Comment: my understanding was that i could send multiple parameters, where the first param would be the page to open and second param would be something to be used within that page

Comment: You can send any # of parameters but it needs to be in the pretty URL also e.g. `/contact/3` or `/about-us/5`

Comment: ok so if i want to have it that way '/contact/3', how should i do?

Comment: sorry anubhava, but i am stuck once again. It does rewrite the url like you said, to www.domains.com/information/3, but the page gives 404 for a lot of files like the css and js files. however if i change the path of those files from href="css/style.css" to href="/css/style.css", they do load...do you know if there is a way to fix this from htaccess? cuz its a lot of code refactoring otherwise

Comment: For any pretty URL scheme it is best to use absolute URLs for css,js,images i.e. you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. Alternatively you can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: thanks a lot, you were a great help, gonna take your advice :)... best answer ever!

Comment: one thing though, now when i change from a page that displays www.domain.com/content/6 (www.domain.com/index.php?show=content&id=6) to a normal page (www.domain.com/index.php?show=home), it results in www.domain.com/content/index.php?show=home ... what should i do? :O